# Advice needed from experts about ASP.NET UserControl usage

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need some advice here. I have a bunch of 10 products and every product has **atleast 200 different pages**  associated with it, with varying details about the product. That makes around 2000 pages.

The structure of each page is as follows:

**Product Name
Details About the product ( 500 words or more)

ProductImage | PurchaseDetails**

When a product page loads, I have to read the productname and display a box at the end of the page. This box should pick up an Productimage and PurchaseDetails that corresponds to the productname. For eg: if there is a product called 'AceShampoo', there is an image associated with it called 'aceshampoo.jpg'. Now I cannot read either the image or the description from the database, since it is not stored there. Only the ProductName and Details come from the DB.

My question to experts:

How and where do I store the ProductImage and the PurchaseDetails for fastest and best performance. Also since there are around 200 pages associated with each product, I would want a way where I can cache this and depending on the parameter i.e productname, change the values.

**Update:** Some products do not have an image or purchase details. So I want to display no details or rather not show it to the users.

How do I go about it. A sample code with explanation would help this novice understand it better.

Thank you for reading this post.

Answer (score 0):

> Now I cannot read either the image or the description from the database, since it is not stored there.

No wonder you have 2000 pages to manage. Is there a reason you can't store the images in the database as BLOBs or the product descriptions? This sort of dynamic content is why you would use a database on the back end.